# Jquery animation not working when clicking quickly on links

Tags: jquery, html, animation, scroll

Here is my code,
this code scrolls a div from the bottom of the page to the top.
I have 3 links that each one scrolls another div and hides the div behind it. 
if if wait till the animation finishes, all works great.
If i don't wait and i quickly click the links it doesn't work.
the animation get stuck and sometimes it doesn't show any div.

what can be the problem?

The CSS:

```
.footerDiv{
display:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:900;
top:800px;
left:0px;
background-size:100%;
height: 600px;
width:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom;} #fourth{background-image:url(../images/group_bg.jpg);} #fifth{background-image:url(../images/team_bg.jpg);} #sixth{background-image:url(../images/client_bg.jpg);}
```

the javascript:

```
function showFooterLink(num){
var bottomOfScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

$("#footerLinks a").each(function(index, element) {
    var elemNum = $(element).attr("data-num");
    if(elemNum==num){
        $(element).addClass("on");
    }
    else{
        $(element).removeClass("on");
    }
});

$('.footer_'+num).stop().
    css({
        "display":"block",
        "z-index":1000
    }).
    animate({
        top: bottomOfScroll - $(window).height()
    }, {
    duration: 1500,
    specialEasing: {
        top: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
    complete: function() {

        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $(".footerDiv").each(function(index, element) {
            if(!$(element).hasClass("footer_"+num)){
                $(element).hide();
                $(element).css({
                    "top"       : bottomOfScroll,
                    "z-index"   : 900
                });
            }
            else{
                $(element).css("z-index","900");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try passing some booleans to the stop method:

Change

```
stop()
```

to

```
stop(true, true)
```

The first bool will clear the animation queue. The second will "jump to the end" of the animation, thus preventing the animation from getting stuck somewhere "in the middle".

> **clearQueue** A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
>
> **jumpToEnd** A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: _I added it but it didn't help._  
You can see the site here:[link](http://91.202.171.113/$sitepreview/ben-natan.com/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/index.html)  
the links are in Hebrew on the bottom of the page.

Comment: @user1879725 `The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: See the link here: http://91.202.171.113/$sitepreview/ben-natan.com/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/index.html

Comment: Can someone please tell me what am I doing worng?